# How to check multiple sql statements violation

Tags: android, sqlite

is there any good idea to check whether an executing query has one statement or multiple statements?

I know SQLiteDatabase.execSQL allows 1 statement in Android sqlite, but sometimes I forget it and execute multiple sql statements at once. Unfortunately it causes no warning nor SqlException.

```
public class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(final SQLiteDatabase db) {
        db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE mytable1 (id INTEGER,value TEXT);"
                + "CREATE TABLE mytable2 (id INTEGER,value TEXT);");
    }

...
```

Thanks.